# How to check the Bundle Version of a iOS App on the phone connected via USB using the command line?

Tags: ios, macos, command-line, ipa, info.plist

I wanted to know if there is a way to get the `Bundle Version` of a `iOS` App on the phone connected via `USB` using the `command line` (from a `Mac` running on `OSX`)?

I have seen a solution in which you need to download the `IPA` application and then unzip it and read the `Info.plist` file to find the `Bundle Version` and `bundle version string short` but I wanted to know if there is a way or tool to directly get the version from the phone without having to download the App/`IPA`.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ideviceinstaller utility from libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller).

You can use the `-l` flag to list all apps installed on the device. Use the `-o xml` flag to make the utility list the results in an XML format.

On Mac, you can install ideviceinstaller using Homebrew. On Linux, be aware that the copies of libimobiledevice which ship with the various Linux distributions are usually out of date, so you're better off installing from source.